# What is the term for a physical division in a newspaper?

Tags: word-request, terminology

There are newspapers that are made up of several "mini-newspapers" (or "physical volumes"), for example, the  "main news" "mini-newspaper", the "classifieds" "mini-newspaper", and the "sports" "mini-newspaper". These "mini-newspapers"/"physical volumes" are placed one on top of another (the "main news" is always the top "mini-newspaper"), and sold to the reader.

What is the correct term for a "mini-newspaper"/"physical volume"?

I thought about "newspaper section", but each "mini-newspaper" could consist of sections too (e.g. the "main news" "mini-newspaper" could consist of sections named "domestic news" and "international news"). "newspaper section" also doesn't capture the fact that the divisions are physical.

Comment: You will probably find that different newspapers have their own convention for naming the portions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is in the same in the UK, but in any case in the US these can be referred to as "page" or "pages", depending on the context.  Historically, a child might nave said to his father, reading the morning paper over breakfast:

> Can you turn to the **sports page**, Dad?  I want to see who won last night's match.

The term still applies to the online version of the newspaper:

> Hey, go click over to the **sports page**, would you?  I want to see who won last night's match.

In many larger newspapers there is the *front* page, the *financial* pages, the *local* pages, the *sports* pages, the *editorial* pages, the *entertainment* pages, and the *classified ads*, as well as various others.  Some newspapers have specialized pages on different days of the week, like *food* pages (with recipes and restaurant reviews) or *society* pages (with news about the local rich and famous).

Note that these are called different "sections" of the newspaper as well, but you asked for an idiomatic alternative.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate because in my newspaper, the sports pages are inside another "volume". Historically, a child would have asked his father "Can you **pass** me the sports "mini-newspaper"/"volume", Dad?". Why do you have to wait for your turn when the "mini-newspapers" can just be separated?

Comment: Flux, you are imagining a level of precision in everyday speech which is unrealistic.

Comment: The word section is more commonly used to indicate the divisions being discussed.

Comment: @Flux  Different papers are organized differently, but the sections are referred to in the same way regardless.  All of my local larger newspapers are separated this way, so, for example, so you could hand over the sports page while still reading the main page.  As children my brothers and I would always open the Sunday paper and pull out the *comics* page, which was separate from the rest of the paper.

Comment: +1 In casual speech, I've always heard people refer to them as the *X page*. They *are* actually sections, but that's not as idiomatic.

Comment: @Flux  It's possible the term has fallen into disuse as newspapers are increasingly online, but older folks like me are creatures of habit.

Answer (score 1):

*Section* is, in my experience, the conventional, everyday term for the different physical parts of a newspaper, excluding the magazine, advertising inserts, and other components that are not printed at the same size. *Page* or *pages* as Andrew suggests are also in use, as well as *feature*, but I think of these as parts of the newspaper within a section, rather than as discrete components of it. The *science pages* might be two pages with a "Science" heading within the main news section, the *religion page* might be a single article in the lifestyle section.

What is idiomatic will likely depend on what kind of newspapers you are accustomed to reading. It is mostly broadsheets that are traditionally split up into different areas of focus, whereas the division is less useful and less common in tabloid-sized publications, although the latter may have a central section that can be pulled out. Growing up in the 1980s mostly reading the *Los Angeles Times* and the *Orange County Register*, I would ask for the *business section* or *opinion section*; on weekdays, when there was no separate opinion section, I would ask for the *news section* or *front page section* because the editorials were printed at the back of it, where I could find the *opinion pages*.

Macmillan's [first definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/section_1) states

> 1a. a part of a newspaper, book, or other piece of writing that may be considered separately
>
> > The story was reported on the front page of the business section.

The *sports section* is probably the most universal, and indeed has its own OED sub-entry with three examples:

> - 1912   *Oakland* (Calif.) *Tribune* 15 June 1/1   A well-edited sports section, contributed to by experts.
> - 1940   G. Marx *Let.* in G. Marx et al. *Groucho Lett.* (1967) 46   I picked up the paper Tuesday morning, nervously turned to the sports section.
> - 2004   *Guardian* 12 Jan. (Media section) 8/1   We expect not just a newspaper, but also a weekend section, an arts section, a blow-by-blow sports section, [etc.].

For examples of other kinds of sections, you might consult guides from the *[Boston Globe](http://archive.boston.com/bostonglobe/1024new/)* and *[The Washington Post](https://nie.washingtonpost.com/teachers-manual)*.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the additional material takes the form of **supplements** - these might be a magazine, TV listings, art reviews, etc, each inserted in the newspaper as a kind of mini newspaper (or magazine). 
(Source here: https://www.inpublishing.co.uk/articles/supplements-1682 )

Comment: What if the "mini-newspaper"/"physical volume" is an integral part of the newspaper? For example, the "main news" "volume" and "finance" "volume" cannot be considered "supplements".

Answer (score 0):

The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pull-out) has

> **pull-out**
>   NOUN
>
> **1A**  pull-out section of a magazine or newspaper.
>   *don't miss Monday's 8-page Games pull-out*.

The question and this definition mention the [word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/section)

> **section**
>   NOUN
>
> **1.1** A relatively distinct part of a book, newspaper, statute, or other document.
>   *the New York Times business section*